# Concatenating results to a list during loop iteration

Tags: python, pandas

I have a bunch of a files in a directory. I want to run a loop on all the files and then concatenate the results to 3 individual lists and then convert them to a dataframe.

```
data= pd.DataFrame({'Date':['10/2/2011', '11/2/2011', '12/2/2011', '13/2/2011'], 
                   'Product':['Umbrella', 'Umbrella', 'Badminton', 'Shuttle'], 
                   'Last Price':[1200, -1500, 1600, 352], 
                   'Updated Price':[1250, 1450, 1550, 400], 
                   'Discount':[10, 10, 10, 10]})
```

So, I summed 3 columns then I want to append the results to their individual lists when looping. Where I'm having issues is appending summation results via the nested loop. Would appreciate if someone could provide color where I am going wrong in the nested loop.

```
for i in files:
    df= pd.read_csv(i,sep="|", low_memory = False)
    Total_Uncalibrated = df[Last_Price].sum()
    Total_Uncalibr = []
    for Total_Uncalibrated:
        uncali = Total_Uncalibrated
        Total_Uncalibr.append(uncali)

    Total_Calibrated = df[Discount].sum()
    Total_Cali = []
    for cali in Total_Cali:
        df3= pd.Dataframe(Total_Calibrated)
        Total_Cali.append(df3)
        TotalCS01_Ab =     df[Updated_Price].sum()
    TotalCS01 = []
    for total in TotalCS01_Abs:
        df4 = pd.Dataframe(Total_Abs)
        TotalCS01_Abs.append(df4)

Expected result s/b:
result_df = pd.concat([Total_Uncalibr,Total_Cali])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite all of your loops like this:

```py
Total_Uncalibr = []

for i in files:
    df= pd.read_csv(i,sep="|", low_memory = False)
    Total_Uncalibrated = df[Last_Price].sum()
    Total_Uncalibr.append(Total_Uncalibrated)
```

You should read up on [loops in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements).

Comment: Thank you Tom. I sure need more practice on loops. Thanks for the help. However when running the above getting error msg that ''float object is not iterable''

Comment: sorry, I read your question-code poorly. I re-wrote my answer, try the above, I only did it for Total_Uncalibrated but you should see how to extend it to all 3 sums you'd like to collect. You need to initialize your lists outside of the ```for i in files:``` loop, or else you will make a new list every iteration and lose your previous sums.